# Почему программа не выдаёт ответ?

Tags: python

```
for x in '01':
    for y in '01':
        for z in '01':
            for w in '01':
                if not(((x <= y) == (z <= w)) or (x and w)):
                    print(x, y, z, w)
```

Comment: Ошибка в операторе if похоже.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

У вас то, что внутри `not` никогда не бывает равно `False`. Проблема во втором выражении `(x and w)`. Для символов это выражение будет давать на выходе тоже символы. Даже если в первой части `((x <= y) == (z <= w))` и получится `False`, то `or` в этом случае даст то, что получилось в правой части, т.е. символ `0` или `1`. А после `not` любой из этих символов даст `True`, потому что символ - это не пустая строка.